# Delete all rows after last occurrence of value within group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large (500,000 row) dataset with ID and weekdays (1-7), and I want to delete all rows after the final occurrence of week day number 7 for all IDs.

Here is a simplified example.

Dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L,2L,2L,2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,3L,3L,3L), 
                                   .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),
                     B = c(1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L,1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L,1L, 1L, 2L, 7L)), 
                .Names = c("ID","Weekday"), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

This code works perfectly on this simplified dataset:

```
df.out<-df %>% 
  group_by(ID)%>%
  dplyr::slice(1:max(which(Weekday == "7")))
```

But when I try it on my large dataset I get the following error:

```
Error in 1:max(which(weekday == "7")) : result would be too long a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In max(which(weekday == "7")) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I have tried with weekday as numeric, factor and integer and no luck.

I can't seem to reproduce this error in a simplified dataset suited to this platform, so I'm not sure how to demonstrate it further, but any help on how to get around this error would be appreciated!

I have used similar code on the large dataset to delete all rows before the first occurrence with no issues. E.g.

```
df.out<-df %>% 
 group_by(ID)%>%
 dplyr::slice(which.max(weekday == "1") : n())
```

Comment: Try this example, the problem is the `which` has no match: `max(which(mtcars$cyl == 11))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be reproduced if you have an `ID` which has no 7 in it.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- rbind(df, data.frame(ID = 'd', Weekday = 1))

df %>% 
    group_by(ID)%>%
    slice(1:max(which(Weekday == "7")))
```

> Error in 1:max(which(Weekday == "7")) : result would be too long a vector

The solution would be to check if you have at least one occurrence of 7.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID)%>%
  slice(if(any(Weekday == 7)) 1:max(which(Weekday == 7)) else 0) %>%
  ungroup

#   ID    Weekday
#   <fct>   <dbl>
# 1 a           1
# 2 a           7
# 3 a           1
# 4 a           1
# 5 a           2
# 6 a           7
# 7 a           1
# 8 a           2
# 9 a           3
#10 a           1
# … with 13 more rows
```

Comment: In `slice` if you return 0 it will not select any row.  (See `mtcars %>% slice(0)`). So this will drop those `ID`'s that have no 7 in them.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean to delete my comment. But thank you, that makes sense.

If I wanted it to find the last occurrence of 6 if there is no 7, would this work?

df %>% 
  group_by(ID)%>%
  slice(if(any(Weekday == 7 )) 1:max(which(Weekday == 7)) else if(any(Weekday == 6 )) 1:max(which(Weekday == 6)))%>%
  ungroup

Comment: Yes and that followed by `else 0` if 6 is not present.

Answer (score 2):

We may also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID)%>%
  slice(seq_len(max(c(0, which(Weekday == 7)[-1])))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 23 x 2
   ID    Weekday
   <fct>   <dbl>
 1 a           1
 2 a           7
 3 a           1
 4 a           1
 5 a           2
 6 a           7
 7 a           1
 8 a           2
 9 a           3
10 a           1
# … with 13 more rows
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
    Weekday = c(1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 
    1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(between(row_number(), 1, which(Weekday == 7)[sum(Weekday == 7)]))

# A tibble: 23 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
   ID    Weekday
   <fct>   <int>
 1 a           1
 2 a           7
 3 a           1
 4 a           1
 5 a           2
 6 a           7
 7 a           1
 8 a           2
 9 a           3
10 a           1
# ... with 13 more rows
```